# How to splice a tensor without knowing the dimensions?

Tags: pytorch, tensor

Say I had a tensor `x` of shape `(21, 256, *)`, how could I get the equivalent of `x[:, :48, ...]` programmatically?

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could do this in pure python since

```py
y = x[:, :48, ...]
```

is equivalent to

```py
y = x[[slice(None), slice(None, 48), Ellipsis]]
```

We can construct the list of slices programmatically

```
dim = 1
slices = [slice(None)] * dim + [slice(None, 48)] + [Ellipsis]
y = x[slices]
```

Note that the ellipsis isn't actually necessary because `x[:, :48]` and `x[:, :48, ...]` are equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent for the above question would be to use [`torch.index_select`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.index_select.html):

```
indexes = torch.arange(48)
torch.index_select(myTensor, 1, indexes)
```